# Domain of the function and its simplified expression

Tags: calculus

I have 3 questions that I'm working on right now and it is these:
Give its domain and simply for each function and sketch the graph of function (I can sketch it by myself once I'm sure that it is all correct)

So for domain and simplification:

1. $$f(x)=\frac{x+3}{x^2-9}$$

   I solved this and got $\frac1{x-3}$ with the domain of $(-\infty,-3)\cup(-3,3)\cup(3,\infty)$.
2. $$f(x)=\frac{-x}{3-\sqrt{x+9}}$$

   I solved this and got $3+\sqrt{x+9}$ with the domain of $x\ge0$.
3. $$\left|\frac{x-2}{3x-6}\right|$$

   I solved this until $\left|\frac{x-2}{3(x-2)}\right|$ and then I'm stuck with simplification and finding domain. I assume I should make it in the form of piecewise defined function, but I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: is it $|\frac{x-2}{3x-6}|$

Comment: no its just x-2 that has absolute value sign :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=\frac{x+3}{x^2-9}=\frac{x+3}{(x+3)(x-3)}=\frac{1}{x-3}$

$x$ cannot be $3$ because if $x=3$ the denominator will become $0$ and division by $0$ is not defined, any other number substituted for $x$ will give you a real value, so domain of the function is $(-\infty,3)\cup(3,\infty)$

$f(x)=\frac{-x}{3-\sqrt{x+9}}$, here $(x+9)$ must be $\geq 0$ so $x$ can assume values $[-9,\infty)...(I)$,

but since $3-\sqrt{x+9}$ is in denominator, $3-\sqrt{x+9}\neq 0 \Rightarrow 3\neq\sqrt{x+9}\Rightarrow 9\neq x+9 \Rightarrow x\neq 0...(II)$,

combining  $(I), (II)$ the domain is $[-9,0)\cup(0,\infty)$

$f(x)=\frac{|x+2|}{3x-6}$

when $(x+2)$ is $\geq 0$ then $f(x)=\frac{x+2}{3(x-2)}$

when $(x+2)$ is $< 0$ then $f(x)=\frac{-(x+2)}{3(x-2)}$

find the domian for above two cases and then combine them

Comment: i think for #3, the domain for both of the cases is all real numbers except for x=2 am i correct?

Comment: @kiko, yes, you are correct

Comment: ok so it i were to write this as a interval notation it would be (-infinity,2)U(2,infinity) right?? im asking this because sometimes its open interval and sometimes its closed interval.. I'm a bit confused on these. And for #1, isn't there supposed to be -3 also in the domain?? i learned that we need to include it in the domain even if we simplified it down. Or matbe i'm mistaken

Comment: @kiko, square brackets$[,]$ means both the extreme points are included, $(,)$ both the extreme points are not included, $[,)$ means left point is included and right point is not included, $(,]$ means left point is not included and right point it included; so yes, $(-\infty, 2)\cup(2,\infty)$ is correct and for #1 $(-\infty, 3)$ implies all the points between $-\infty$ and $3$ are included and that includes $-3$

Comment: thank you! just one more question, for #2, i can leave the equation as it is or do I have to simplify it down? for me it seems like there's nothing to simplify. I want to vote you up but i need 15 reputation..

Comment: @kiko, the one simplification possible is getting rid of one of the negative signs, the simplified expression would be $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+9}-3}$, No problem if you can't upvote, knowing that you want to upvote is enough :)

Answer (score 0):

You already simplified the function in #3 enough. Just ask yourself, "what values of $x$ are not allowed?"

Also, for #2, I'm assuming that the given function is $f(x)= \dfrac{-x}{3-\sqrt{x+9}}$.

That makes your answer partially correct but incomplete. Can you think of more $x$-values that are allowed?

Comment: for #2, the simplifed expression is 3+sqrt(x+9) am I correct? the domain would be all real numbers except for -9 and 0